# Some Form Data Is Not Being Posted To The Database

Tags: php, cakephp

So, I have run into a minor issue and i don't know what is going wrong. I have some data i needed to add to a form and thus the database. I created the database field, named it 'visit_nature' with `varchar` datatype then went ahead and created the form field.

```
<div class="controls-row" id="visitNature">
  <div class="span2">
  <?php echo $this->Form->label('visit_nature', 'Symptomatic or Asymptomatic', array('class'=>'required')); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="span10">
  <?php 
    echo $this->Form->input('visit_nature', array(
         'options' => array('Symptomatic' => 'Symptomatic', 
                            'Asymptomatic' => 'Asymptomatic'),
         'empty' => '--Select Vist Nature--',
         'class'=>'validate[required]',
         ));
    ?>
  <span class="help-inline">Does the patient have symptoms or not</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

now, the funny thing is, when you inspect the network request, the data from there is visible, but it never makes it to the database, the other fields on the form are posted.
These are shown

`_method:"POST",data[PatientVisit][patient_id]:"784"data[PatientVisit][visit_nature]:"Symptomatic"`

Why would it not send the data to the database?!

Comment: Echo your SQL query. Does all the data exists?

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek i had somehow forgotten i had to clear the cache in the tmp folder. It worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

You used the select option wrong. I'm not positive this is your source of error, but it should look like this:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('visit_nature', array(
     'options' => array('Symptomatic', 'Asymptomatic'),
     'empty' => '--Select Vist Nature--',
     'class'=>'validate[required]',
     ));
?>
```

Comment: the previous one worked well. I only had to clear the cache, in app/tmp/cache.